# Fineuploader : how to replace uploaded images?

Tags: javascript, fine-uploader

I'm using fine uploader to upload images. After I upload an image, I need to be able to upload another image to replace the uploaded image before and only allow one image at one time. Is there any options for that or should I delete the upladed image before I start uploading the new one?

Answer (score 1):

This is what I would do:

1. Set the [`multiple` configuration option](https://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/options-ui.html#multiple) to `false`. This will be most helpful if you are using the UI built into the Fine Uploader library (and not a custom UI or React Fine Uploader. In that case, after a file has been submitted, subsequent files will "replace" that initial file in the UI.
2. Remove/replace the item on your server when handling the upload request if a file for that user already exists.

This is making a lot of assumptions as you have provided very little information about your situation or setup. This should get you started down the right path though.

Answer (score -1):

End up deleting the uploaded images before uploading a new one:

```
                onValidate: function() {
                    this.deleteFile(avatar_id);
                }
```